# Associate App Access Token with User Access Token to invoke the Azure REST API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, authorization, azure-web-app-service, access-token

I have appId and secret to generate access token. But I want to create user access token to invoke the Azure REST API to list of all the subscription to be listed based user access permission.
Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a user access token without either the user signing in or having the user credentials as well.

The typical approach to get data as a user is to log in the user and access the API on their behalf (e.g. Authorization Code flow).

Comment: Thanks Juunas for response. I am ok to provide login option to capture user credential. But it didn't generate the token